# HTML Selenium Python click on href link

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, href, nosuchelementexception

I would like to write a python code where he clicks on the href link.

Screenshot of HTML:
[image: screenshot of HTML code]

This is what I am currently having in Python, but it does not work.

```
tables = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="notice"]')

for table in tables:
     row = table.find_element_by_xpath('//tr[@class="Zebra"]//td//a[@href="https://enot.publicprocurement.be/enot-war/preViewNotice.do?noticeId=438868&saveSearchParams=true&pageSize=%31%32%35&d-446978-p=%31&"]').click()
```

This is the error message for row:

```
NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//tr[@class="Zebra"]//td//a[@href="https://enot.publicprocurement.be/enot-war/preViewNotice.do?noticeId=438868&saveSearchParams=true&pageSize=%31%32%35&d-446978-p=%31&"]"}
```

Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desired element is a *`<a>`* element with the *innerText* as ***Universiteit Antwerpen-22004***

To click on the desired element you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using the *href* attribute:

  ```
  table.find_element_by_xpath('.//tr[@class="Zebra"]//td//a[starts-with(@href, "https://enot.publicprocurement.be/enot-war/preViewNotice.do?noticeId")]').click()
  ```
- Using the *innerText*:

  ```
  table.find_element_by_xpath('.//tr[@class="Zebra"]//td//a[contains(., "Universiteit Antwerpen-22004")]').click()
  ```

Comment: Thanks, it works. However, I have another question. How can I refer to the output:
"BME-BME - CSC 2022-008"

This is the HTML code:

[<tr class="Zebra">
<td>
<a href="preViewNotice.do?noticeId=443287&amp;saveSearchParams=true&amp;pageSize=%31%32%35&amp;d-446978-p=%31&amp;">
                        BME-BME - CSC 2022-008
                    </a>
</td>
<td>2022-513912</td>
<td>

And this is my Python code (which works):
total = soup.findAll('tr',{'class':'Zebra'})

print(total)

in other words, how can I refer to the words after href ? 

thanks!

Comment: @mathias5986 Glad to be able to help you. Feel free to raise a new question as per your new requirement.